# O que significa "Em Tempo de Execução"?

Tags: c#

Eae Galera tudo bom?
Em minhas pesquisas sempre encontro referencias ao termo **"Em tempo de execução"**, Mas procurando o termo para conseguir mais informações, não consigo localizar nada relevante.

Gostaria de entender oque significa **"Em tempo de execução"**, e o oposto dele oque não é **"em tempo de execução"**.

E quais as vantagens para a aplicação, ou para o programador?

**Abaixo exemplos de documentações onde encontrei o termo:**

> "*LINQ to SQL* é um componente do .NET Framework versão 3.5 que fornece uma infraestrutura **de tempo de execução** para gerenciar dados relacionais como objetos." [Microsoft Docs Linq to Sql](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/)
>
> "O tipo *dynamic* habilita operações nas quais ele ocorre para ignorar a verificação de tipo em tempo de compilação. Em vez disso, essas operações são resolvidas **em tempo de execução.**" [Microsoft Docs Dynamic](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/dynamic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Em tempo de execução" ou *"Runtime"* é algo que ocorre quando o programa está sendo executado basicamente.

Pra ilustrar, pense em analisar um código. Um erro pode acontecer em tempo de compilação ou em tempo de execução.

Veja esse código:

```
int x = 1;
int z = x/0;
```

Isso dá um erro de divisão por zero em "tempo de compilação", pois o compilador consegue validar isso sem precisar executar o código ("tempo de execução").  Mas se o código fosse assim:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;
y--;
int z = x/y;
```

Não daria erro em tempo de compilação, pois o compilador não vai executar as operações matemáticas, neste caso decrementar o valor de y, mas isso vai dar um erro de divisão por zero em "tempo de execução", ou seja quando o código for executado.

Uma observação, na pergunta tem o texto *"Em tempo de execução", e o oposto dele oque não é "em tempo de execução"* mas eles não são opostos, ele só acontecem em tempos diferente, o "tempo de compilação" acontece antes, quando o código em linguagem de alto nível é "traduzido" para uma linguagem de baixo nível que o computador/dispositivo possa entender, o outro é a seguir, quando o código está em execução (*running*).

Comment: Então esses termos são usados somente para informação de como funciona o recurso? não oferece nenhuma vantagem para aplicação? Performance ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Sim, para indicar um evento ou estado de quando o programa está em execução ou não. Se você diz algo "em tempo de execução", é que acontece quando o programa está sendo executado.

Comment: Obrigado. é um conceito meio difícil de pegar só lendo documentações.

Answer (score 0):

Em informática, **`tempo de execução`** ou **`runtime`** (termo em inglês), é o período em que um programa de computador permanece em execução. O termo runtime também pode se referir a uma máquina virtual que gerencia um programa escrito em uma linguagem de computador enquanto está sendo executado.

O termo tempo de execução é um contraponto ao termo tempo de compilação, que é uma referência ao período em que o código é compilado para gerar um programa executável.

Um ambiente de tempo de execução é um estado da máquina virtual que proporciona serviços de software para processos ou programas enquanto o computador está rodando. Ele pode pertencer ao sistema operacional mesmo, ou ao programa que roda abaixo dele. O propósito inicial é alcançar o objetivo de programação "independente de plataforma".

Atividades de tempo de execução incluem carregar e ligar bibliotecas necessárias para executar o programa, geração de código de máquina opcional e otimização dinâmica do programa, e a execução do programa de fato.

**Fonte: Wikipedia**